# Twitter raw JSON Spring social Twitter

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-twitter

How to get original JSON data tweet using spring social Twitter API ? There is "Tweet" class, but I didn't find any function that allows to retrieve original tweet content- returned by Twitter in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you want the raw JSON data but it is possible and here is how you can fetch it:

Follow this [Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/) to setup Spring Social Twitter.

If you want raw JSON data from Twitter then you can use the `RestTemplate` obtained from `TwitterTemplate`.

Add this Controller in above guide:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jsontweets")
public class JsonTweetsController {

    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    private TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate;

    @Inject
    public JsonTweetsController(Twitter twitter, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository, TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate) {
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
        this.twitterTemplate = twitterTemplate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloTwitter(@RequestParam String search, Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/twitter";
        }

        Connection<Twitter> con = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        UserProfile userProfile = con.fetchUserProfile();
        String username =  userProfile.getFirstName() + " " + userProfile.getLastName(); 

        RestTemplate restTemplate = twitterTemplate.getRestTemplate();

        //More Query Options @ https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets    
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q="+search, String.class);
        System.out.println("JSON Response From Twitter: "+response);

        model.addAttribute("jsonstring", response);
        model.addAttribute("username", username);

        return "json";
    }

}
```

Add a template to view raw tweets `json.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Tweets</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Hello, <span th:text="${username}">Some User</span>!</h3>
        <div th:text="${jsonstring}">JSON Tweets</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Check the complete [Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream) and the latest [Commit](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/commit/0e94f05fd0ca18bb440e5bfe65306e8d255380b0) for above code.